# Exposing kafka internal metrics via Micrometer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, micrometer

I believe there are various ***internal metrics of the kafka-client code. I am wandering how to expose those metrics.*** I want to expose the internal metrics, how to do in scala.
Can you give me a hint how to start and few lines of code.
I want to expose for example these metrics:
**-committed-time-ns-total

-fetch-size-avg,

-records-consumed-rate**
Any feedback will be appreciated.

I am blank at the moment I dont know how to start

Comment: It'd be easier to get metrics if you used a framework like Spring, Quarkus, Vert.x, etc

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use Micrometer? I'd use OpenTelemetry auto instrumentation (java agent) and just see what you get out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring-Kafka, the client is instrumented out of the box for you.
Micrometer also supports Kafka's internal metrics, you just need to enable this, see: [`KafkaClientMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/779b98668d3beb6210cbf039aa95502f407bc5c8/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaClientMetrics.java) and [`KafkaStreamsMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaStreamsMetrics.java). But the best would be adding Micrometer support to the Kafka Client itself, we do have an issue for this, please if you think you could benefit from it, leave a comment on it so that Kafka maintainers consider implementing it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15191